# Spark Worker not joining Master after Master dies and comes back

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-standalone

I was wondering on how often does Worker pings Master to check on Master's liveness? Or is it the Master (Resource manager) that pings Workers to check on their liveness and if any workers are dead to spawn ? Or is it both?

Some info:
Standalone cluster
1 Master - 8core 12Gb
32 workers - each 8 core and 8 Gb

My main problem - Here's what happened:

Master M - running with 32 workers
Worker 1 and 2 died at 03:55:00 - so now the cluster is 30 workers

Worker 1' came up at 03:55:12.000 AM - it connected to M
Worker 2' came up at 03:55:16.000 AM - it connected to M

Master M dies at 03:56.00 AM 
New master NM' comes up at 03:56:30 AM
Worker 1' and 2' - DO NOT connect to NM
Remaining 30 workers connect to NM.

So NM now has 30 workers.

I was wondering on why those two won't connect to new master NM even though master M is dead for sure.

PS:I have a LB setup for Master which means that whenever a new master comes in LB will start pointing to new one.

Answer (score 1):

Load balancer won't resolve your problem here. For Spark workers to recognize a new master you have to configure Spark in a high availability mode. Spark standalone supports two HA configurations:

- Standby master with ZooKeeper.
- Node recovery using file system.

The latter solution is much simpler but requires a reliable, distributed file system to store `spark.deploy.recoveryDirectory`, unless you recover master on the same node of course.

Recovery mode can be configured using `spark.deploy.recoveryMode` property (`NONE` [by default](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#deploy)) which should be set to `ZOOKEEPER` and `FILESYSTEM` for standby and node recovery respectively.

More details can be found in [High Availability](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#high-availability) documentation.

Related: [What happens when Spark master fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35815386/6910411)